# Make: *.h no such file or directory

Tags: c, makefile, cuda, gnu-make, nvcc

My project has the following directory structure:

- main.cu
- FA_kernels/*.cu
- FD_kernels/*.cu
- MEM_kernels/*.cu
- MOD_kernels/*.cu
- headers/*.h

Where *.extension means a bunch of files with that extension. I can't seem to get the makefile to work correctly. The error I'm getting is:

```
 FA_kernels/FA_SFD.cu:2:20: fatal error: FA_SFD.h: No such file or directory
 #include "FA_SFD.h"
                    ^
```

My intent was for -I headers to be specified to the compiler, thereby making the headers directory available for searching. Clearly this has not worked. Here is the makefile:

```
CC        := nvcc
LD        := nvcc

MODULES   := FA_kernels FD_kernels MEM_kernels MOD_kernels .
SRC_DIR   := $(MODULES)
BUILD_DIR := $(addprefix build/,$(MODULES))

SRC       := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.cu))
OBJ       := $(patsubst src/%.cu,build/%.o,$(SRC))
INCLUDES  := $(addprefix -I,headers)

vpath %.cu $(SRC_DIR)

define make-goal
$1/%.o: %.cu
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $$< -o $$@
endef

.PHONY: all checkdirs clean

all: checkdirs build/lem

build/lem: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $^ -o $@


checkdirs: $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @rm -rf build

$(foreach bdir,$(BUILD_DIR),$(eval $(call make-goal,$(bdir))))
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Here is the full console output from running make

```
nvcc FA_kernels/FA_SFD.cu FA_kernels/partition.cu FA_kernels/contribA.cu FA_kernels/parallel-SFD-List.cu FD_kernels/SFD.cu FD_kernels/flow_routines.cu FD_kernels/floodingDriver.cu FD_kernels/watershed.cu MEM_kernels/memory_dev.cu MEM_kernels/Data.cu MEM_kernels/MapInfo.cu MEM_kernels/memory.cu MOD_kernels/erosion.cu MOD_kernels/eroincidep.cu MOD_kernels/updates.cu MOD_kernels/runoffweight.cu MOD_kernels/depo-List.cu lem.cu -o build/lem
FA_kernels/FA_SFD.cu:2:20: fatal error: FA_SFD.h: No such file or directory
 #include "FA_SFD.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'build/lem' failed
make: *** [build/lem] Error 1
```

Comment: Paste the compiler invocation as it is printed in the shell.

Comment: @user657267 please see update

Comment: It would be good to show us how you've written the `include` statement as well.

Comment: Ah, there it is.  You need to use the relative path to the header file.

Comment: I see no -I options for the include paths in your compiler output. no compiler will find your included files without them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your output, apparently `patsubst` in `OBJ` was not successful at all. From the way you define SRC, I assume `makefile` is directly under `src/`, then you should change `src/%.cu` to `%.cu` in the definition of `OBJ` as such:

```
OBJ       := $(patsubst %.cu,build/%.o,$(SRC))
```

Also, if I understand you correctly, you were trying to create a folder structure under `build/` that is identical to the folder structure under `src/`. So, for instance, `/src/abc.cu` will generate `/src/build/abc.o`, then you don't need to define functions to get these rules, simply do:

```
build/%.o: %.cu
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

and you are good to go.

If instead you wish to create `build/` on the same level as `src/`. i.e. `XXX/src/abc.cu` -> `XXX/build/abc.o`. Then simply replace all occurrences of `build` in your makefile with `../build`.

If you would rather put makefile at the same level as `src/`, then you should edit `SRC` to reflect that:

```
SRC       := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard src/$(sdir)/*.cpp))
```

and change the target to:

```
build/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

Now you can safely remove `vapth ...` and the last line `$foreach` in your makefile.

EDIT: This is what your makefile will look like. I can't test it right now so there may be some mistakes in it, but hopefully it makes you understand the general idea.

```
CC        := nvcc
LD        := nvcc

MODULES   := FA_kernels FD_kernels MEM_kernels MOD_kernels .
SRC_DIR   := $(MODULES)
BUILD_DIR := $(addprefix build/,$(MODULES))

SRC       := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.cu))
OBJ       := $(patsubst %.cu,build/%.o,$(SRC))
INCLUDES  := $(addprefix -I,headers)

# vpath %.cu $(SRC_DIR) 

#define make-goal
build/%.o: %.cu
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
#endef

.PHONY: all checkdirs clean

all: checkdirs build/lem

build/lem: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $^ -o $@


checkdirs: $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @rm -rf build

#$(foreach bdir,$(BUILD_DIR),$(eval $(call make-goal,$(bdir))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've removed src/ from the path subsitution and it is now working (Or at least failing in an expected manner). My intention is to have the following structure project/*.cu, project/FA_kernels/*.cu, project/build/*.cu, project/build/FA_kernels/*.cu etc. I don't fully understand your suggestions for changes, would you be so kind to post a full makefile with your suggested changes so that I can better understand you? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I got that I needed to remove src/ from the path substitution, but what I was asking was what would my makefile look like if I implemented your suggestions "you don't need to define functions to get these rules, simply do:
build/%.o: %.cu
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@"

Comment: ah, just seen what you've commented out